# Why don't Borg drones run?

Tags: star-trek, borg

It seems that they have the physical ability to run and yet we never see them doing this, even when quicker movements would more benefit the completion of their goals. To quickly stop an opponent from activating some release mechanism or complete some computer command procedure would seem a worthy reason to move more quickly yet they move zombie like no matter the situation or task at hand. Is there some reason that they only walk and not run when it would seem more appropriate to do so?

As an addition, there are multiple examples of 'former' Borg drones being able to run and/or move very quickly.

Comment: @Richard - That's actually pretty close but the 3 answers there are: 
1) There is no in-universe "canon" reason why the Borg move the way they do;
 
2)The real reason the Borg move so slowly is because they had no need for fast mobility. Fast mobility in the Borg's eyes represents desperation; 3) It's pure writing. Everyone knows that slowly moving robots (and monsters) are more scary... Sorry but those aren't acceptable answers to my question.

Comment: #1 is the answer to your question. They don't run because they're written as "slow moving"

Comment: @Richard -No in-universe "canon" reason? Are you sure? Humans, Klingons and Vulcans can run before they're assimilated but then suddenly they can't after assimilation? There must be a reason.

Comment: @Richard -To answer 'It was written that way' would answer every question at SE. I'm looking for a bit more than, "That's how the writers wrote it".

Comment: @Richard -Is it because the hive mind in control of them can't react quickly enough or isn't suited to quick mental inputs or physical stimuli? The explanation for this discrepancy must be there right in front of us...

Comment: You're projecting your human individuality onto them. Losing a single drone (or even a million drones) isn't a big deal to them as long as it gives them vital info to help adapt to future threats and become more perfect. Note that they're happy to blow up half the galaxy to find out more about the Omega particle.

Comment: The answers on that question may not be acceptable to you, but this doesn't make your question unique. This is indeed a duplicate by first sight. If you aren't satisfied with the answers there, launch a bounty on that.

Comment: @SachinShekhar -I never said my question was completely unique. I had no idea that similar question existed until Richard pointed it out. Even so, the 3 'answers' tendered there fall far short of actually answering my question. I guess I'll have to discover the real answer without help from here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is they do not have to, you will get hammered by another Borg down the line or they will re-position their contingent with technology. Running is very wasteful in this light.

Comment: In the original question wording I said 'Borg drones' but Sachin Shekhar apparently decided to edited it to 'Borgs'.

Comment: I just fixed that edit.

Comment: Actually they have failed many times because they moved too slowly.

Comment: @Morgan - They gather vital intelligence from their failures, allowing them to adapt.

Comment: The Borg MO seems to be: Beam into target area, one or two task drones to accomplish specific task, warrior drones are just there to soak up damage and ensure task is accomplished. Losses are irrelevant as long as task is done. Fighting back is irrelevant except to protect the task. The collective doesn't WANT to kill anyone - they want to ASSIMILATE. From their POV, they're doing everyone a favor - we're just too primitive to understand that.